# What's the name of that old Italian comedy movie with a suitcase full of money?

Tags: identify-this-movie

So I saw part of this movie in an Italian restaurant (with English subtitles) and it seemed really funny so here are all the details I remember :

- The movie is old, Italian, black and white, probably from the 50's
- The characters are all trying to get a suitcase with a lot of money in it since they are poor
- They steal it from a guy who asks them to knock him off so that he can say it was stolen and he couldn't do anything about it
- They had a technique so that their car could change color and that it won't be recognized by the police
- There is a man that was hidden in a dumpster and goes back to his wife to tell her they're about to be rich since his friends found the suitcase

That's about all that I can remember since it was playing during a dinner with my family in the background of the restaurant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'd be *L'audace colpo dei soliti ignoti* (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audace_colpo_dei_soliti_ignoti) for the English Wikipedia and [here](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audace_colpo_dei_soliti_ignoti) for the Italian one, with more details), also known as *Fiasco in Milan*, directed in 1959 by Nanni Loy, with Vittorio Gassman, Renato Salvatori and Claudia Cardinale.

It was a sequel to the more renowned [*I soliti ignoti*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Deal_on_Madonna_Street) (1958) by Mario Monicelli.

(I am not sure whether it is legit, but the film can be found on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/NhjTqJw3blU), with the not-exactly-hi-tech colour-changing car from 56:20.)